# how to post ajax data and not standard form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to post a simple input field as json data to a webserver that i created.
Now i have done this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(event){
        $('#postit').submit(function(){


            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://ihavearealurltoaserverhere',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              data: JSON.stringify($('#postit').serializeObject()),
                complete: function() {
                //called when complete
                alert("DOET HET");
              },

              success: function(data) {
                //called when successful
                alert("success DOET HET " + data);
             },

              error: function() {
                  alert("DOET HET niet");
                //called when there is an error
              }

        });




        });

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="postit">
  <input name='name' value='asd'>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

<pre id="result">moi
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

If i now click on submit then in my webservice  i receive 2 respones.
In one i get a POST(checked with wireshark) where i got the normal form data(if i check with CGI) i see request_method = name="asd", and secondly for the AJAX post i receive a GET(as i can see in wireshark) with the restants of my URL so for example if i post to www.bla.com/test then i get test&{name:%asd} and in CGI i see this in a QUERY_STRING

Why does my ajax not just send it as normal post?

**Anwser:**
make use of `e.preventDefault();` to stop the form from submitting.
and use  `$.post('http://example', JSON.stringify($('#postit').serializeObject()));` instead of ajax because, if you use ajax with dataType:json from another domain then you get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and if you use jsonp then it actually won't post but use GET, see answer below for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `e.preventDefault()` to the top of your function, to stop the form from submitting.

```
$('#postit').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://ihavearealurltoaserverhere',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        data : JSON.stringify($('#postit').serializeObject()),
        complete : function () {
            //called when complete
            alert("DOET HET");
        },

        success : function (data) {
            //called when successful
            alert("success DOET HET " + data);
        },

        error : function () {
            alert("DOET HET niet");
            //called when there is an error
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: but then i only get the standard form post data, and then i don't get the AJAX data

Comment: Really? You should get the AJAX data but not the form post data, if you do this. Do you need both? If so, set a data attribute on the form, say data-should-submit which is originally set to false, when the AJAX returns, set it to true and resubmit the form... At the top of the function, e.preventDefault() if false and return if true, so the AJAX doesn't submit a second time.

Comment: i only need to have the json data.. but i must receive it as post and not as a GET

Comment: Put e.preventDefault() at the top of your function (remember to pass e in as a parameter to your function) then use: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: ok it only works when i use this:  $.post('http://pexamle', JSON.stringify($('#postit').serializeObject()));

But why does the ajax not work normally then ?

Comment: I think it might be something to do with setting dataType to jsonp... This actually appends a new JavaScript file to your page with the url you specified, which is a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: ah ok because if i do normal json then it wont work because of access control allow origin